# Continuous function satisfying a given inequality is a bijection

Tags: real-analysis

f:R→R is a continuous function such that |f(x)-f(y)|>=log{1+|x-y|) for all x,y in R. Prove that f is bijective. Injectivity of f is clear since f(x)=f(y) implies x=y. Surjectivity of f is the problem.  y=0 gives |f(x)|>=log(1+|x|)-f(0). When x is large |f(x)| is large. Also continuous injection is stricly monotone. How do I conclude f is surjective? Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is increasing. Then $f(0+y)-f(0) \geq \log (1+ y) \to \infty$ as $y \to \infty$ so $f(y) \to \infty$ as $y \to \infty$. Similarly, $f(0)-f(0-y) \geq \log (1+ y) \to \infty$ so $f(-y) \to -\infty$ as $y \to \infty$. By IVP these facts imply that $f$ attains every real value.

A similar argument works if $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have found so far,  $f$ is strictly monotonic.
Pick $y\in \Bbb R$. Then for $x:=\exp(|f(0)|+|y|)$, the values $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ both differ by at least $\log(1+x)>|f(0)|+|y|$ from $f(0)$, one of them  being $>f(0)$, the other $<f(0)$. Then one of $f(\pm x)$ must be $<f(0)-|f(0)|-|y|\le y$ and the other $>f(0)+|f(0)|+|y|\ge y$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $\xi\in[-x,x]$ wiht $f(\xi)=y$.

Comment: f(x) and f(-x) differ by at least log(1+2x). Am I correct?